# Let $X,Y$ Banach, if every Gateaux derivative of $f \colon X \to Y$ exists is continuous is then $f$ Frechet differentiable?

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $f \colon A \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ for $A$ open. We know that if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x) $ exists for every $x \in A$ and is continuous for every $i \leq n$ (i.e. $f \in C^1(A)$) then by standard theory $f$ is differentiable.

Now consider $X, Y$ to be infinite dimensional Banach spaces and let $f \colon A \subset X \to Y$ for $A$ open and suppose that the Gateaux derivative along the direction $h \in X$ $D_hf(x)$ exists $x \in A$ and  is continuous for every $h \in X$ (or if you have a basis $e_i$ that $D_{e_i}f(x)$  is continuous for every $e_i$). Does it follow that $f$ is Frechet differentiable like in the finite dimensional case?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3084800/how-to-prove-that-frechet-derivative-exists-and-coincides-with-the-gateau-deriva?rq=1

Comment: yes but that question assumes that the Frechet derivative is continuous. I only assume that the Gateaux derivative are continuous. Is it equivalent?

Comment: No. It assumes that the Gateaux derivative is continuous. How can it assume that the Frechet derivative is continuous before even proving that  Frechet derivative  exists?

Comment: Yes right I missread